# Why Excel file from .NET Core Web Api is corrupt?

Tags: excel, angular, epplus, asp.net-core-webapi, filesaver.js

I am using .NET Core with *EPPlus.Core* to generate Excel files, intended to create reports. Unfortunately, the Excel data is corrupted somewhere between server and client (Angular2) where I use *FileSaver.js* to save the Excel file to disk.

This is my Web API controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    try
    {
        var report = await _reportService.GetReportAsync();
        var mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        var fileBytes = report.Bytes;
        return File(fileBytes, mimeType, report.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception);
        throw;
    }
}
```

This is the report service:

```
public async Task<Report> GetReportAsync()
{
    byte[] bytes;
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employee");
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Name";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Gender";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Salary (in $)";

        worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 1000;
        worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Jon";
        worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = "M";
        worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 5000;

        worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = 1001;
        worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "Graham";
        worksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = "M";
        worksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 10000;

        worksheet.Cells["A4"].Value = 1002;
        worksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "Jenny";
        worksheet.Cells["C4"].Value = "F";
        worksheet.Cells["D4"].Value = 5000;
        bytes = package.GetAsByteArray();

        /* WORKS FINE - FILE IS SAVED AND IS NOT CORRUPT */
        const string path2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xlsx";
        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(path2, bytes);
        /* WORKS FINE - FILE IS SAVED AND IS NOT CORRUPT */

    }
    return new Report(bytes);
}
```

This is the client code:

```
this.http.get(this.baseUri + uri, query).subscribe(response => {
if (response.status === 200) {
        let fileSaver = require('file-saver');
        let mediaType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
        let blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: mediaType });
        let filename = 'test.xlsx';
        fileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
    }
});
```

The file *test2.xlsx* is saved successfully and opens without problems. If I open it in *Notepad++* I can see binary like this:

[image: test2.xlsx]

The file *test.xlsx* downloaded by the Angular2 client fails to open in Excel because data is corrupted and if I open that file in Notepad++ I can see that there is a a difference - valid characters are replaced by crap:

[image: test.xlsx]

I have read a number of similar questions but nothing has been able to put me in the right direction. A few of the things I have tried:

- Returning an application/octet-stream instead of Excel file
- Using XHR instead of Angular *http.get* (cannot get this to work because I use Windows Negotiate token and I have no idea how I can use this token type with XHR)
- Tried returning an HttpResponseMessage instead of File like this:

> var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage {Content = new
>   ByteArrayContent(report.Bytes)};
>   httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", report.Name);
>   httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new
>   MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
>   httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new
>   ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {FileName =
>   Path.GetFileName(report.Name)};
>   httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength =
>   report.Bytes.Length; httpResponseMessage.StatusCode =
>   HttpStatusCode.OK; return httpResponseMessage;

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925334/excel-file-download-through-web-api-getting-corrupt) is related but not the same, my file is corrupt to the degree it cannot be repaired and opened.

Any suggestions? Could it be an encoding issue?

**UPDATE**

Hex dump of **valid** Excel file:

> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B E4 48  AD AF 18 01 00 00 33
>   03 00 00 13 00 00 00 5B 43  6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 5F 54 79 70 65 73 5D 2E
>   78 6D  6C B5 92 CF 4A 03 31 10 C6 5F 65 C9 55 9A B4 1E  44 A4 DB 1E AA
>   1E 55 B0 3E C0 98 CC 76 43 F3 8F  CC B4 B6 6F 6F 36 2B 22 A5 82 1E 7A
>   9A 24 DF CC  F7 FD 08 33 5F 1E BC 6B F6 98 C9 C6 D0 8A 99 9C  8A 06 83
>   8E C6 86 4D 2B DE D6 8F 93 5B D1 10 43  30 E0 62 C0 56 1C 91 C4 72 31
>   5F 1F 13 52 53 66  03 B5 A2 67 4E 77 4A 91 EE D1 03 C9 98 30 14 A5  8B
>   D9 03 97 6B DE A8 04 7A 0B 1B 54 D7 D3 E9 8D  D2 31 30 06 9E F0 E0 21
>   16 F3 7B EC 60 E7 B8 59  8D EF 83 75 2B 20 25 67 35 70 C1 52 C5 4C 34
>   0F  87 22 8E 94 C3 5D FD 61 6E 1F CC 09 CC E4 0B 44  66 74 B5 87 7A 9B
>   E8 EA 34 A0 A8 34 24 3C 97 8F  C9 D6 E0 BF 22 62 D7 59 8D 26 EA 9D 2F
>   23 92 52  46 30 D4 23 B2 77 B2 56 E9 C1 86 31 F4 05 32 3F  81 2F AE EA
>   E0 D4 47 CC DB F7 18 B7 B2 6A 17 01  18 22 EA F9 B7 FC 2A 92 AA 65 76
>   41 10 E2 A3 43  3A 47 31 2A 97 8C EE 21 A3 79 E5 5C 96 FC 3C C1  CF 86
>   6F 10 55 97 7E F1 09 50 4B 07 08 E4 48 AD  AF 18 01 00 00 33 03 00 00
>   50 4B 03 04 14 00 08  00 08 00 11 59 66 4B 98 DA EB 8B AE 00 00 00 27 
>   01 00 00 0B 00 00 00 5F 72 65 6C 73 2F 2E 72 65  6C 73 8D CF C1 0E 82
>   30 0C 06 E0 57 59 7A 97 81  07 63 0C 83 8B 31 E1 6A F0 01 E6 56 06 01
>   D6 65  9B 0A 6F EF 8E 62 3C 78 6C FA F7 FB D3 B2 5E E6  89 3D D1 87 81
>   AC 80 22 CB 81 A1 55 A4 07 6B 04  DC DA CB EE 08 2C 44 69 B5 9C C8 A2
>   80 15 03 D4  55 79 C5 49 C6 74 12 FA C1 05 96 0C 1B 04 F4 31  BA 13 E7
>   41 F5 38 CB 90 91 43 9B 36 1D F9 59 C6  34 7A C3 9D 54 A3 34 C8 F7 79
>   7E E0 FE D3 80 AD  C9 1A 2D C0 37 BA 00 D6 AE 0E FF B1 A9 EB 06 85  67
>   52 8F 19 6D FC 51 F1 95 48 B2 F4 06 A3 80 65  E2 2F F2 E3 9D 68 CC 12
>   0A BC 2A F9 E6 C1 EA 0D  50 4B 07 08 98 DA EB 8B AE 00 00 00 27 01 00
>   00  50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B 9C 2D  27 53 C1 00 00 00
>   4D 01 00 00 0F 00 00 00 78 6C  2F 77 6F 72 6B 62 6F 6F 6B 2E 78 6D 6C
>   8D 8E B1  0E C2 30 0C 44 77 24 FE 21 CA 07 10 60 60 A8 52  16 60 40 42
>   82 89 3D A4 2E 8D 48 E2 C8 49 55 F8  7B D2 56 45 B0 B1 DD 9D CF 4F 27
>   3B A4 C7 0D F1  C1 9E CE FA 58 50 C9 9B 94 42 21 44 D4 0D 38 15  17 18
>   C0 E7 5B 8D E4 54 CA 96 EE 02 EB DA 68 D8  A3 6E 1D F8 24 D6 CB E5 46
>   10 58 95 0C FA D8 98  10 F9 48 FB 87 15 03 81 AA 62 03 90 9C 1D 51 4E 
>   19 CF B7 F3 19 63 B2 5F 76 35 D0 C5 C1 E6 60 9A  DB 87 4C 8C 25 F1 DB
>   92 03 EC F3 31 38 E6 95 83  92 1F 5C B0 F8 02 E0 6C 48 8F 55 C9 57 9C
>   51 61  B2 A0 63 95 F5 84 FC 62 48 AD AC BE 10 AB 5B 6B  77 59 9E FD 09
>   D5 F8 D9 B7 A5 98 36 6D DF 50 4B  07 08 9C 2D 27 53 C1 00 00 00 4D 01
>   00 00 50 4B  03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B 81 62 92 A2  D6 00 00
>   00 34 02 00 00 1A 00 00 00 78 6C 2F 5F  72 65 6C 73 2F 77 6F 72 6B 62
>   6F 6F 6B 2E 78 6D  6C 2E 72 65 6C 73 AD 91 CF 6A C3 30 0C 87 5F C5  E8
>   BE 38 E9 60 8C 51 B7 97 31 E8 B5 7F 1E 40 D8  4A 1C 9A D8 C6 D2 DA E5
>   ED 6B 36 56 52 28 63 87  9E 84 64 F4 FD 3E AC E5 FA 6B 1C D4 89 32 F7
>   31  18 68 AA 1A 14 05 1B 5D 1F 3A 03 87 FD C7 D3 2B  28 16 0C 0E 87 18
>   C8 C0 44 0C EB D5 72 4B 03 4A  59 61 DF 27 56 85 11 D8 80 17 49 6F 5A
>   B3 F5 34  22 57 31 51 28 2F 6D CC 23 4A 69 73 A7 13 DA 23  76 A4 17 75
>   FD A2 F3 9C 01 B7 4C B5 71 06 F2 C6  35 A0 F6 53 A2 FF B0 63 DB F6 96
>   DE A3 FD 1C 29  C8 9D 08 7D 8E F9 C8 9E 48 0A 14 73 47 62 E0 3A  62 FD
>   5D 9A AA 50 41 DF 97 59 3C 52 86 65 1A CA  5F 5E 4D 7E FA BF E2 9F 1F
>   1A EF 31 93 DB 49 2E  87 9E 5B CC C7 BF 32 FA E6 DA AB 0B 50 4B 07 08 
>   81 62 92 A2 D6 00 00 00 34 02 00 00 50 4B 03 04  14 00 08 00 08 00 11
>   59 66 4B 2A 7B 81 AB 61 01  00 00 C3 03 00 00 18 00 00 00 78 6C 2F 77
>   6F 72  6B 73 68 65 65 74 73 2F 73 68 65 65 74 31 2E 78  6D 6C 8D 93 DD
>   4E 83 30 18 86 6F A5 E9 B9 2B 7F  9B CB 02 2C 9B 64 D1 33 E3 81 E7 15
>   3E 46 33 A0  A4 ED 86 F7 E6 81 97 E4 2D 58 BA 05 A1 8D C6 B3  16 9E BE
>   EF C3 97 F2 F5 F1 19 6F DF 9B 1A 5D 40  48 C6 DB 04 FB 0B 0F 23 68 73
>   5E B0 F6 98 E0 B3  2A EF D6 78 9B C6 3D 17 27 59 01 28 A4 F1 56 6E  44
>   82 2B A5 BA 0D 21 32 AF A0 A1 72 C1 3B 68 F5  BB 92 8B 86 2A BD 15 47
>   C2 CB 92 E5 90 F1 FC DC  40 AB 48 E0 79 2B 22 A0 A6 4A 57 C9 8A 75 12
>   5F  D3 FE 93 25 3B 01 B4 30 0A 4D 7D 8D 6A 28 6B 71  1A 17 4C A7 0F F6
>   48 40 99 E0 9D BF C9 22 8C 48  1A 1B F8 95 41 2F 27 6B 34 7C C9 1B E7
>   A7 61 F3  54 24 D8 33 2C 71 E0 83 29 7F 16 A8 80 92 9E 6B  F5 C2 FB 47
>   60 C7 4A E9 21 2D 7F F2 33 AA 68 1A  0B DE 23 3D 12 5F EB E4 C3 62 E7
>   63 24 4D B6 C6  A5 7E 7A 49 BD 98 5C 74 4F 7E 23 F6 2E E1 CF 89  07 97
>   08 E6 44 E6 12 E1 48 10 ED 34 8A 05 A3 58  70 3B 62 0A 3D CF B6 0A 9C
>   C4 C8 B2 72 89 A5 65  35 AD 58 4E 2B 66 4A E1 A8 14 CE 95 AC 31 EC 43 
>   A7 70 65 29 B9 84 AD 64 55 FC E6 14 8D 4E D1 FC  80 35 F8 7D E4 34 DE
>   5B 4E 2E B1 B6 9C A2 BF C7  44 26 D7 AB D2 57 1F C4 81 73 05 C2 DC D6
>   F1 77  4C BF 01 50 4B 07 08 2A 7B 81 AB 61 01 00 00 C3  03 00 00 50 4B
>   03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66  4B FC 8A 2B 3D 46 01 00 00 69 03 00
>   00 0D 00 00  00 78 6C 2F 73 74 79 6C 65 73 2E 78 6D 6C 8D 53  4D 6F 83
>   30 0C BD 4F DA 7F 88 F8 01 4B 5B 69 3B  4C B0 CB 24 A4 5D 7A E9 0E BB
>   86 92 40 24 E7 43  89 99 60 BF 7E 40 D2 26 9D 98 D4 9B FD 9E F3 9E  B1
>   4D E9 71 02 7E EA 39 47 32 2A D0 BE 2A 7A 44  FB 4A A9 3F F7 5C 31 FF
>   64 2C D7 33 23 8C 53 0C  E7 D4 75 D4 5B C7 59 EB 97 47 0A E8 61 B7 7B
>   A1  8A 49 5D BC 3D 3E 10 52 EA 41 D5 0A 3D 39 9B 41  63 55 EC 0A 42 03
>   21 8C 4E F0 3E 54 47 38 C6 73  E6 7F C8 37 83 99 DF 5F DE AD B0 66 8A
>   07 E2 9D  81 6C 9C 4C 6C 49 AF 0A 21 F4 D1 4E 02 5C ED 0E  C9 6E 86 93
>   AE 65 88 DC E9 7A 06 49 8C 3F 27 CB  AB 42 1B CD 6F 3C D2 B3 7B 25 3A
>   C7 A6 FD E1 79  53 25 84 B1 D3 C6 B8 96 BB 8D D1 04 22 59 01 17  98 4F
>   C5 C9 AE BF 01 D0 D8 3C 6D 0C A2 51 39 D2  4A D6 19 CD 20 EB 29 33 B9
>   24 B1 AF 33 07 38 2D  F7 F1 25 36 9A 1B 05 09 AB FE 68 D7 2D 2F A3 8F 
>   61 5C 38 CD 05 92 E4 5D 6A CC 5A 98 8E 83 6A B8  AB D7 D3 5B 8A 73 8F
>   B5 A0 36 41 85 8C 62 C3 FA  C6 75 ED 63 C3 F8 CA 91 E5 C6 AA E2 B8 B8
>   41 A6  D8 0C 12 50 EA FF 3E 2D 5A B4 A3 F8 7B F2 25 4D  3F D7 DB 2F 50
>   4B 07 08 FC 8A 2B 3D 46 01 00 00  69 03 00 00 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00
>   08 00 11 59  66 4B F3 7E 6F 36 C5 00 00 00 58 01 00 00 14 00  00 00 78
>   6C 2F 73 68 61 72 65 64 53 74 72 69 6E  67 73 2E 78 6D 6C 65 90 41 4A
>   04 31 10 45 AF 12  0A 17 BA 70 D2 BA 10 95 24 B3 50 46 14 74 A3 1E  A0
>   E8 AE 99 0E 74 2A 6D AA 5A EC DB 1B 11 11 32  CB F7 3E FF 17 94 DB 7E
>   A5 C9 7C 52 91 98 D9 C3  C5 A6 03 43 DC E7 21 F2 C1 C3 FB DB EE FC 1A
>   8C  28 F2 80 53 66 F2 B0 92 80 D9 06 27 A2 A6 56 59  3C 8C AA F3 AD B5
>   D2 8F 94 50 36 79 26 AE C9 3E  97 84 5A B1 1C AC CC 85 70 90 91 48 D3
>   64 2F BB  EE CA 26 8C 0C A6 CF 0B AB 87 1B 30 0B C7 8F 85  EE FE B8 1E
>   88 C1 69 78 BC 77 56 83 B3 3F F4 6B  5E 30 51 EB 1E 88 07 2A AD 7D C5
>   09 CB 6A 4E 23  9B 93 B3 36 7C CA DC AA E7 A3 D9 82 23 A6 A3 26  31 AF
>   AD DC FD 0B 5B 5F 13 BE 01 50 4B 07 08 F3  7E 6F 36 C5 00 00 00 58 01
>   00 00 50 4B 01 02 2D  00 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B E4 48 AD AF 18 
>   01 00 00 33 03 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 5B 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E  74 5F 54 79 70 65 73 5D 2E 78 6D 6C 50 4B
>   01 02  2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B 98 DA EB 8B  AE 00 00 00 27
>   01 00 00 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 59 01 00 00 5F 72
>   65 6C 73 2F  2E 72 65 6C 73 50 4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08  00 11 59
>   66 4B 9C 2D 27 53 C1 00 00 00 4D 01 00  00 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 40  02 00 00 78 6C 2F 77 6F 72 6B 62 6F 6F 6B 2E 78  6D
>   6C 50 4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59  66 4B 81 62 92 A2 D6 00
>   00 00 34 02 00 00 1A 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3E 03 00
>   00  78 6C 2F 5F 72 65 6C 73 2F 77 6F 72 6B 62 6F 6F  6B 2E 78 6D 6C 2E
>   72 65 6C 73 50 4B 01 02 2D 00  14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B 2A 7B 81
>   AB 61 01  00 00 C3 03 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
>   5C 04 00 00 78 6C 2F 77 6F 72 6B 73  68 65 65 74 73 2F 73 68 65 65 74
>   31 2E 78 6D 6C  50 4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B  FC 8A
>   2B 3D 46 01 00 00 69 03 00 00 0D 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 03 06 00 00 78 6C  2F 73 74 79 6C 65 73 2E 78 6D 6C 50 4B 01 02 2D 
>   00 14 00 08 00 08 00 11 59 66 4B F3 7E 6F 36 C5  00 00 00 58 01 00 00
>   14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 84 07 00 00 78 6C 2F 73 68
>   61 72  65 64 53 74 72 69 6E 67 73 2E 78 6D 6C 50 4B 05  06 00 00 00 00
>   07 00 07 00 C2 01 00 00 8B 08 00  00 00 00

Hex dump of **corrupted** Excel file:

> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53 66 4B  EF BF BD 48 EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 18 01 00 00 33 03  00 00 13 00 00 00 5B 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74
>   5F 54  79 70 65 73 5D 2E 78 6D 6C EF BF BD EF BF BD EF  BF BD 4A 03 31
>   10 EF BF BD 5F 65 EF BF BD 55 EF  BF BD EF BF BD 1E 44 EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD 1E EF BF  BD 1E 55 EF BF BD 3E EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  76 43 EF
>   BF BD CC B4 EF BF BD 6F 6F 36 2B 22 EF  BF BD EF BF BD 1E 7A EF BF BD
>   24 EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 08 33 5F 1E EF BF BD 6B EF  BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD D0 8A EF BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF BD 06 EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD C6 86 4D  2B EF BF BD D6 8F EF BF BD 5B EF BF BD 10 43
>   30  EF BF BD 62 EF BF BD 56 1C EF BF BD EF BF BD 72  31 5F 1F 13 52 53
>   66 03 EF BF BD EF BF BD 67 4E  77 4A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 03 C9
>   98 30 14  EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 03 EF BF BD 6B DE A8  04 7A 0B 1B
>   54 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF  BD 31 30 06 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD 21 16 EF  BF BD 7B EF BF BD 60 EF BF BD 59 EF BF BD EF BF  BD 75
>   2B 20 25 67 35 70 EF BF BD 52 EF BF BD 4C  34 0F EF BF BD 22 EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD 5D  EF BF BD 61 6E 1F EF BF BD 09 EF BF BD EF BF BD 
>   0B 44 66 74 EF BF BD EF BF BD 7A EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF BD 34 EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD 34 24 3C EF BF  BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 22
>   62 EF  BF BD 59 EF BF BD 26 EF BF BD 2F 23 EF BF BD 52  46 30 EF BF BD
>   23 EF BF BD 77 EF BF BD 56 EF BF  BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 31 EF BF BD 05
>   32 3F EF BF  BD 2F EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 47 EF  BF BD EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD 18 EF BF BD EF BF BD 6A  17 01 18 22 EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD  2A EF BF BD EF BF BD 65 76 41 10 EF BF BD 43 3A  47
>   31 2A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 21 EF BF BD  79 EF BF BD 5C EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 3C EF BF BD CF  86 6F 10 55 EF BF BD 7E EF BF BD 09 50 4B 07
>   08  EF BF BD 48 EF BF BD EF BF BD 18 01 00 00 33 03  00 00 50 4B 03 04
>   14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53  66 4B EF BF BD EF BF BD EB 8B AE 00 00
>   00 27 01  00 00 0B 00 00 00 5F 72 65 6C 73 2F 2E 72 65 6C  73 EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD 0E EF BF BD 30 0C  06 EF BF BD 57 59 7A EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD 07 63 0C  EF BF BD EF BF BD 31 EF BF BD 6A EF BF BD 01 EF  BF BD
>   56 06 01 EF BF BD 65 EF BF BD 0A 6F EF BF  BD 62 3C 78 6C EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD D3 B2  5E EF BF BD 3D D1 87 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 
>   22 CB 81 EF BF BD 55 EF BF BD 07 6B 04 EF BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD 08 2C 44 69 EF BF BD  EF BF BD C8 A2 EF BF BD 15 03 EF BF BD 55
>   79 EF  BF BD 49 EF BF BD 74 12 EF BF BD EF BF BD 05 EF  BF BD 0C 1B 04
>   EF BF BD 31 EF BF BD 13 EF BF BD  41 EF BF BD 38 CB 90 EF BF BD 43 EF
>   BF BD 36 1D  EF BF BD 59 EF BF BD 34 7A C3 9D 54 EF BF BD 34  EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 79 7E EF BF BD EF BF BD D3 80  EF BF BD EF BF BD 1A 2D EF BF
>   BD 37 EF BF BD 00  D6 AE 0E EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 06  EF
>   BF BD 67 52 EF BF BD 19 6D EF BF BD 51 EF BF  BD 48 EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   06 EF BF BD EF BF BD 65  EF BF BD 2F EF BF BD EF BF BD 68 EF BF BD 12
>   0A  EF BF BD 2A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  0D 50 4B 07 08 EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD EB 8B AE 00 00  00 27 01 00 00 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00
>   08 00 EF  BF BD 53 66 4B EF BF BD 2D 27 53 EF BF BD 00 00  00 4D 01 00
>   00 0F 00 00 00 78 6C 2F 77 6F 72 6B  62 6F 6F 6B 2E 78 6D 6C EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD EF BF  BD 0E EF BF BD 30 0C 44 77 24 EF BF BD 21 EF BF  BD 07
>   10 60 60 EF BF BD 52 16 60 40 42 EF BF BD  EF BF BD 3D EF BF BD 2E EF
>   BF BD 48 EF BF BD EF  BF BD 49 55 EF BF BD 7B EF BF BD 56 45 EF BF BD 
>   EF BF BD DD 9D EF BF BD 4F 27 3B EF BF BD EF BF  BD 0D EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF  BD 58 50 C9 9B EF BF BD 42 21 44 EF BF BD
>   0D 38  15 17 18 EF BF BD EF BF BD 5B EF BF BD EF BF BD  54 CA 96 EF BF
>   BD 02 EF BF BD EF BF BD 68 D8 A3  6E 1D EF BF BD 24 EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 46  10 58 EF BF BD 0C EF BF BD D8 98 10 EF BF BD 48  EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 15 03 EF BF BD EF BF BD 62 03  EF BF BD EF BF BD 1D 51 4E 19
>   CF B7 EF BF BD 19  63 EF BF BD 5F 76 35 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF
>   BF BD 60 EF BF BD DB 87 4C EF BF BD 25 EF BF  BD DB 92 03 EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD 31 38 E6 95 83 EF  BF BD 1F 5C EF BF BD EF BF BD 02 EF BF BD 6C
>   48  EF BF BD 55 EF BF BD 57 EF BF BD 51 61 EF BF BD  EF BF BD 63 EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  62 48 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 10 EF
>   BF BD 5B  6B 77 59 EF BF BD EF BF BD 09 EF BF BD EF BF BD  D9 B7 EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD 36 6D EF BF BD 50 4B 07  08 EF BF BD 2D 27 53 EF BF BD 00
>   00 00 4D 01 00  00 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53 66  4B EF
>   BF BD 62 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 00 00  00 34 02 00 00 1A 00 00 00
>   78 6C 2F 5F 72 65 6C  73 2F 77 6F 72 6B 62 6F 6F 6B 2E 78 6D 6C 2E 72 
>   65 6C 73 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 6A EF BF BD  30 0C EF BF BD 5F EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD 38 EF BF BD  60 EF BF BD 51 EF BF BD EF BF BD 31 EF BF
>   BD 7F  1E 40 EF BF BD 4A 1C EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 6B 36 56 52  28 63 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 64
>   EF BF BD EF  BF BD 3E EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 6B 1C D4 89  32 EF BF
>   BD 31 18 68 EF BF BD 1A 14 05 1B 5D 1F  3A 03 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD 2B 28  16 0C 0E EF BF BD 18 EF BF BD EF BF BD 44 0C EF  BF
>   BD EF BF BD 72 4B 03 4A 59 61 EF BF BD 27 56  EF BF BD 11 D8 80 17 49
>   6F 5A EF BF BD EF BF BD  34 22 57 31 51 28 2F 6D EF BF BD 23 4A 69 73
>   EF  BF BD 13 EF BF BD 23 76 EF BF BD 17 75 EF BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   01 EF BF BD 4C EF BF BD 71 06  EF BF BD EF BF BD 35 EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   53 EF BF  BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 63 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF  BD DE A3 EF
>   BF BD 1C 29 C8 9D 08 7D EF BF BD EF  BF BD C8 9E 48 0A 14 73 47 62 EF
>   BF BD 3A 62 EF  BF BD 5D EF BF BD EF BF BD 50 41 DF 97 59 3C 52  EF BF
>   BD 65 1A EF BF BD 5F 5E 4D 7E EF BF BD EF  BF BD EF BF BD 1F 1A EF BF
>   BD 31 EF BF BD EF BF  BD 49 2E EF BF BD EF BF BD 5B EF BF BD C7 BF 32 
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD DA AB 0B 50 4B 07 08 EF BF BD  62 EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 00 00 00 34 02 00  00 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD
>   53 66  4B 2A 7B EF BF BD EF BF BD 61 01 00 00 EF BF BD  03 00 00 18 00
>   00 00 78 6C 2F 77 6F 72 6B 73 68  65 65 74 73 2F 73 68 65 65 74 31 2E
>   78 6D 6C EF  BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 4E EF BF BD 30 18 EF BF  BD 6F EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD 2B 7F EF BF BD EF BF BD  02 2C EF BF BD 64 EF BF BD 33
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD  15 3E 46 33 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  E6
>   81 97 EF BF BD 2D 58 EF BF BD 05 EF BF BD EF  BF BD C6 B3 16 EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD C3 97  EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 19 6F DF 9B 1A 5D
>   40  48 EF BF BD EF BF BD 04 EF BF BD 0B 0F 23 68 73  5E EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 2A EF BF  BD EF BF BD 78 EF BF BD EF BF BD 3D 17
>   27 59 01  28 EF BF BD EF BF BD 56 6E 44 EF BF BD 2B EF BF  BD EF BF BD
>   0D 21 32 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  72 EF BF BD 3B 68 EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF  BF BD EF BF BD 2A EF BF BD 15 47 EF BF BD CB 92  EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 40 EF BF BD  48 EF BF BD 79 2B 22 EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD 4A 57 C9  8A 75 12 5F EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 25 3B 01 
>   EF BF BD 30 0A 4D 7D EF BF BD 6A 28 6B 71 1A 17  4C EF BF BD 0F EF BF
>   BD 48 40 EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 22 EF BF BD 48
>   1A 1B  EF BF BD EF BF BD 41 2F 27 6B 34 7C EF BF BD 1B  EF BF BD 61 EF
>   BF BD 54 24 EF BF BD 33 2C 71 EF  BF BD EF BF BD 29 7F 16 EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF BD 6B EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 47 60  EF BF BD
>   4A EF BF BD 21 2D 7F EF BF BD 33 EF BF  BD 68 1A 0B EF BF BD 23 3D 12
>   5F EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF BD 62 EF BF BD 63 24 4D EF BF BD C6 A5  7E
>   7A 49 EF BF BD EF BF BD 5C 74 4F 7E 23 EF BF  BD 2E EF BF BD CF 89 07
>   EF BF BD 08 EF BF BD 44  EF BF BD 12 EF BF BD 48 10 EF BF BD 34 EF BF
>   BD  05 EF BF BD 58 70 3B 62 0A 3D CF B6 0A EF BF BD  EF BF BD C8 B2 72
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD 65 35 EF BF  BD 58 4E 2B 66 4A EF BF BD 14 CE 95 EF
>   BF BD 31  EF BF BD 43 EF BF BD 70 65 29 EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF BF BD 64
>   55 EF BF BD EF BF BD 14 EF BF BD 4E  EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 35 EF
>   BF BD 7D EF BF  BD 34 EF BF BD 5B 4E 2E EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 44 26 D7 AB EF BF  BD 57 1F C4 81 73 05 EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD  EF BF BD 77 4C EF BF BD 01 50 4B 07 08 2A 7B EF 
>   BF BD EF BF BD 61 01 00 00 EF BF BD 03 00 00 50  4B 03 04 14 00 08 00
>   08 00 EF BF BD 53 66 4B EF  BF BD EF BF BD 2B 3D 46 01 00 00 69 03 00
>   00 0D  00 00 00 78 6C 2F 73 74 79 6C 65 73 2E 78 6D 6C  EF BF BD 53 4D
>   6F EF BF BD 30 0C EF BF BD 4F EF  BF BD 7F EF BF BD EF BF BD 01 4B 5B
>   69 3B 4C EF  BF BD EF BF BD 24 EF BF BD 5D 7A EF BF BD 0E EF  BF BD EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD 40 24 EF BF BD 43 EF BF  BD EF BF BD 60 EF BF BD 7E 40
>   EF BF BD 26 EF BF  BD EF BF BD D4 9B EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 4D  EF
>   BF BD 71 02 7E EF BF BD 39 47 32 2A D0 BE 2A  7A 44 EF BF BD 4A EF BF
>   BD 3F EF BF BD 5C 31 EF  BF BD 64 2C EF BF BD 33 23 EF BF BD 53 0C EF
>   BF  BD EF BF BD 75 EF BF BD 5B EF BF BD 59 EF BF BD  47 0A EF BF BD 61
>   EF BF BD 7B EF BF BD EF BF BD  49 5D EF BF BD 3D 3E 10 52 EF BF BD 41
>   EF BF BD  0A 3D 39 EF BF BD 41 63 55 EF BF BD 0A 42 03 21  EF BF BD 4E
>   EF BF BD 3E 54 47 38 EF BF BD 73 EF  BF BD 7F EF BF BD 37 EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD  5F DE AD EF BF BD 66 EF BF BD 07 E2 9D 81 6C EF  BF BD
>   4C 6C 49 EF BF BD 0A 21 EF BF BD EF BF BD  4E 02 5C EF BF BD 0E EF BF
>   BD 6E EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF BD 65 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 7A 06 
>   49 EF BF BD 3F 27 CB AB 42 1B EF BF BD 6F 3C D2  B3 7B 25 3A C7 A6 EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD 79 53 25 EF  BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD C6 B8 EF BF BD EF
>   BF BD  EF BF BD EF BF BD 04 22 59 01 17 EF BF BD 4F EF  BF BD C9 AE EF
>   BF BD 01 EF BF BD EF BF BD 3C 6D  0C EF BF BD 51 39 EF BF BD 4A EF BF
>   BD 19 EF BF  BD 20 EF BF BD 29 33 EF BF BD 24 EF BF BD EF BF  BD 33 07
>   38 2D EF BF BD EF BF BD 25 36 EF BF BD  1B 05 09 EF BF BD EF BF BD 68
>   EF BF BD 2D 2F EF  BF BD EF BF BD 61 5C 38 EF BF BD 05 EF BF BD EF  BF
>   BD 5D 6A EF BF BD 5A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF  BD 6A EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD EF BF BD 5B EF  BF BD 73 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 36 41 EF
>   BF  BD EF BF BD 62 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 75 EF  BF BD 63 EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD CA 91 EF BF BD C6 AA  E2 B8 B8 41 EF BF BD EF BF BD 0C 12 50
>   EF BF BD  EF BF BD 3E 2D 5A EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 7B  EF BF BD 25
>   4D 3F EF BF BD EF BF BD 2F 50 4B 07  08 EF BF BD EF BF BD 2B 3D 46 01
>   00 00 69 03 00  00 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53 66  4B EF
>   BF BD 7E 6F 36 EF BF BD 00 00 00 58 01 00  00 14 00 00 00 78 6C 2F 73
>   68 61 72 65 64 53 74  72 69 6E 67 73 2E 78 6D 6C 65 EF BF BD 41 4A 04 
>   31 10 45 EF BF BD 12 0A 17 EF BF BD 70 D2 BA 10  EF BF BD 24 EF BF BD
>   50 46 14 74 EF BF BD 1E EF  BF BD E8 AE 99 0E 74 2A 6D EF BF BD 5A EF
>   BF BD  EF BF BD 1B 11 11 32 EF BF BD EF BF BD 3E EF BF  BD 17 EF BF BD
>   EF BF BD 7E EF BF BD EF BF BD 7C  52 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF
>   BD C5 A6 03  43 EF BF BD EF BF BD 21 EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF  BD EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 1A EF BF  BD 28 EF BF BD 53 66 F2 B0 92
>   80 EF BF BD 06 27  EF BF BD EF BF BD 56 59 3C EF BF BD EF BF BD EF  BF
>   BD D2 8F EF BF BD 50 36 79 26 EF BF BD EF BF  BD 3E EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   5A EF BF BD 1C EF BF BD  CC 85 70 EF BF BD EF BF BD 48 EF BF BD 64 2F
>   EF  BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 26 EF BF BD 0C EF BF BD  EF BF BD 0B EF BF
>   BD EF BF BD 1B 30 0B C7 8F EF  BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 1E EF
>   BF BD EF  BF BD 69 78 EF BF BD 77 56 EF BF BD EF BF BD 3F  EF BF BD 6B
>   5E 30 51 EF BF BD 1E EF BF BD 07 2A  EF BF BD 7D EF BF BD 09 EF BF BD
>   6A 4E 23 EF BF  BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 36 7C EF BF BD DC AA EF BF  BD D9
>   82 23 EF BF BD EF BF BD 26 31 EF BF BD EF  BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 0B
>   5B 5F 13 EF BF BD 01  50 4B 07 08 EF BF BD 7E 6F 36 EF BF BD 00 00 00 
>   58 01 00 00 50 4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00  EF BF BD 53 66 4B EF
>   BF BD 48 EF BF BD EF BF BD  18 01 00 00 33 03 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5B 43 6F 6E 74 65  6E 74 5F 54 79
>   70 65 73 5D 2E 78 6D 6C 50 4B 01  02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD
>   53 66 4B EF  BF BD EF BF BD EB 8B AE 00 00 00 27 01 00 00 0B  00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 59 01 00  00 5F 72 65 6C 73 2F 2E 72 65
>   6C 73 50 4B 01 02  2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53 66 4B EF BF  BD
>   2D 27 53 EF BF BD 00 00 00 4D 01 00 00 0F 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 40 02 00 00  78 6C 2F 77 6F 72 6B 62 6F 6F 6B 2E 78 6D 6C
>   50  4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53 66  4B EF BF BD 62 EF
>   BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD 00 00  00 34 02 00 00 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00  00 00 00 3E 03 00 00 78 6C 2F 5F 72 65 6C 73 2F  77 6F 72 6B
>   62 6F 6F 6B 2E 78 6D 6C 2E 72 65 6C  73 50 4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00
>   08 00 EF BF BD  53 66 4B 2A 7B EF BF BD EF BF BD 61 01 00 00 EF  BF BD
>   03 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 5C 04 00 00 78 6C
>   2F 77 6F 72 6B 73 68  65 65 74 73 2F 73 68 65 65 74 31 2E 78 6D 6C 50 
>   4B 01 02 2D 00 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53 66  4B EF BF BD EF BF BD
>   2B 3D 46 01 00 00 69 03 00  00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 03  06 00 00 78 6C 2F 73 74 79 6C 65 73 2E 78 6D 6C  50 4B 01 02 2D
>   00 14 00 08 00 08 00 EF BF BD 53  66 4B EF BF BD 7E 6F 36 EF BF BD 00
>   00 00 58 01  00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  EF BF BD
>   07 00 00 78 6C 2F 73 68 61 72 65 64 53  74 72 69 6E 67 73 2E 78 6D 6C
>   50 4B 05 06 00 00  00 00 07 00 07 00 EF BF BD 01 00 00 EF BF BD 08  00
>   00 00 00

Comment: Instead of a screenshot of Mojibake it would be better if you posted part of a hexdump

Comment: Sure thing, not sure how that is going to help but by all means... :) The point of the screenshots was simply to demonstrate that the data was different.

Comment: Holy... i just a small piece of the two hexdumps side by side in a monospace font please.

Comment: Actually never mind, in the second hex dump i see a lot of `EF BF BD` which is the UTF-8 sequence of bytes for `U+FFFD`, which is the unicode code point `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` that's used as a replacement when a byte sequence couldn't be decoded to a code point. It appears that you have an encoding issue. You're decoding the bytes to a string somewhere and then again encoding that string to bytes using UTF-8. Do not decode to string anywhere.

Comment: You are right that the encoding differs and I can see this in Notepad++ as well - I guess my question is why? All code from server to client is provided and I can´t see why this is happening.

Comment: I think you're extracting the http response as a string and not as a blob, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149741/how-to-receive-blob-responses-using-angular-2s-angular-http-module

Comment: Yeah, I didn´t realize that it is necessary to specify the `responseType`. Just adding `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob` made the whole difference. Thanks! Post answer so I can accept.

Comment: Im getting same problem but I don't know how to fixed in VueJs. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, i think you're extracting the http response as a string and not as a blob. :)

See [How to receive blob responses using Angular 2's @angular/http module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149741/how-to-receive-blob-responses-using-angular-2s-angular-http-module)

Answer (score 1):

I am also using EPPlus to return an InMemory excel workbook as a byte array, and it is being corrupted only when I run the docker container from a Linux host versus a Windows host.

```
using (var package = ExcelUtil.createExcelPackage(hits))
    {
        reportBytes = package.GetAsByteArray();
    }
return File(reportBytes, XlsxContentType, fileDownloadName);
```

Which in beyondcompare I can see about 14 locations where it always replaces 'C0 A4' with '4F A5' but I don't know the relevance of that. Most of the replacements are near the end of the file and look like such:

[image: hex comparison]

I'm not sure what is causing, but when I figure it out I'll post the answer. I'd make this a comment but the picture seemed relevant and I'm sure we'll come up with something shortly...

Comment: I'm curious if this has to do with the System.Drawing components of EPPlus. I know that is a different library for windows vs linux, and it was something that didn't work on linux until I added to the dockerfile:

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev

Comment: As a side note for anyone looking for a follow-up -- this was because Windows was blocking the file upon download. After right clicking > properties > unblock, it was no different of a file than one from a Windows host. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to decorate Web API function with [AlloyAnonymous] attribute to get Angular http get RequestOptionsArgs, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob accepted and Web API function finally called properly. I guess there should be better workaround.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]        
public IActionResult GetSearchedReportsFile(string fileGuid)
  {            
  byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\epplus\" + fileGuid + ".xlsx");
  return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "myfile.xlsx");            
  }
```